# Cocoapods: Can't access Obj-C pod from Swift pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, cardio

I am building a Swift framework that should wrap another framework/library - the CardIO.
It is going to be distributed as a pod.
So I have added the CardIO pod as dependency in my podspec as follows:

```
s.dependency 'CardIO', '~> 5.0'
s.static_framework = true
```

Now, the problem is that I can't figure out how should I access the CardIO code from my wrapper framework.
I do succeed to access it from the app level code (after adding the corresponding bridging header), but not from the framework.